# i got crash when record : "required condition is false: format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate" afterweb rtc call

Tags: swift, record, avaudiosession

my record work normally, but the problem is after WebRTC call, i got crash

**required condition is false: format.sampleRate == hwFormat.sampleRate**

here is how i start crash and installTap:

```
func startRecord() {
        self.filePath = nil
        
        print("last format: \(audioEngine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate)")
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try session.setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: .mixWithOthers)
        } catch {
            print("======== Error setting setCategory \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        do {
            try session.setPreferredSampleRate(44100.0)
        } catch {
            print("======== Error setting rate \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        do {
            try session.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.005)
        } catch {
            print("======== Error IOBufferDuration \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        do {
            try session.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        } catch {
            print("========== Error starting session \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatInt16,
            sampleRate: 44100.0,
//            sampleRate: audioEngine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate,
            channels: 1,
            interleaved: true)
        audioEngine.connect(audioEngine.inputNode, to: mixer, format: format)
        audioEngine.connect(mixer, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: format)

        let dir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first! as String
        filePath =  dir.appending("/\(UUID.init().uuidString).wav")

        _ = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!) as CFURL,
            kAudioFileWAVEType,(format?.streamDescription)!,nil,AudioFileFlags.eraseFile.rawValue,&outref)

        mixer.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount((format?.sampleRate)!), format: format, block: { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) -> Void in

            let audioBuffer : AVAudioBuffer = buffer
            _ = ExtAudioFileWrite(self.outref!, buffer.frameLength, audioBuffer.audioBufferList)
        })

        try! audioEngine.start()
        startMP3Rec(path: filePath!, rate: 128)
    }

    func stopRecord() {

        self.audioFilePlayer.stop()
        self.audioEngine.stop()
        self.mixer.removeTap(onBus: 0)

        self.stopMP3Rec()
        ExtAudioFileDispose(self.outref!)

        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
    }
    
    func startMP3Rec(path: String, rate: Int32) {

        self.isMP3Active = true
        var total = 0
        var read = 0
        var write: Int32 = 0

        let mp3path = path.replacingOccurrences(of: "wav", with: "mp3")
        var pcm: UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE> = fopen(path, "rb")
        fseek(pcm, 4*1024, SEEK_CUR)
        let mp3: UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE> = fopen(mp3path, "wb")
        let PCM_SIZE: Int = 8192
        let MP3_SIZE: Int32 = 8192
        let pcmbuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>.allocate(capacity: Int(PCM_SIZE*2))
        let mp3buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: Int(MP3_SIZE))

        let lame = lame_init()
        lame_set_num_channels(lame, 1)
        lame_set_mode(lame, MONO)
        lame_set_in_samplerate(lame, 44100)
        lame_set_brate(lame, rate)
        lame_set_VBR(lame, vbr_off)
        lame_init_params(lame)

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            while true {
                pcm = fopen(path, "rb")
                fseek(pcm, 4*1024 + total, SEEK_CUR)
                read = fread(pcmbuffer, MemoryLayout<Int16>.size, PCM_SIZE, pcm)
                if read != 0 {
                    write = lame_encode_buffer(lame, pcmbuffer, nil, Int32(read), mp3buffer, MP3_SIZE)
                    fwrite(mp3buffer, Int(write), 1, mp3)
                    total += read * MemoryLayout<Int16>.size
                    fclose(pcm)
                } else if !self.isMP3Active {
                    _ = lame_encode_flush(lame, mp3buffer, MP3_SIZE)
                    _ = fwrite(mp3buffer, Int(write), 1, mp3)
                    break
                } else {
                    fclose(pcm)
                    usleep(50)
                }
            }
            lame_close(lame)
            fclose(mp3)
            fclose(pcm)
            self.filePathMP3 = mp3path
        }
    }
    
    func stopMP3Rec() {
        self.isMP3Active = false
    }
```

as first time run app, i log the last format using

```
print("last format: \(audioEngine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate)")
```

--> return 0 -> record normally
next time return 44100 -> record normally

but after webrtc call, i got 48000, then it make crash in this line

```
self.audioEngine.connect(self.audioEngine.inputNode, to: self.mixer, format: format)
```

***i spend 4 hour in stackoverflow but no solution work for me.***

i dont want 48000 format, because i have set the sample to

```
sampleRate: audioEngine.inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate,
```

-> my output is hard to hear, i can recognize my voice :(

So i think 44100 is the best

can someone give me some advices? Thanks

Comment: Long story short, my airpods randomly decided to mess with my simulator, I disconnected them and I was back on track.. No idea what exactly happenned~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line bugs.

```
let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatInt16, ...
```

`AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatInt16` not works by default.

You should use `.pcmFormatFloat32`

---

And the xcode tip is obvious,

the crash line

```
self.audioEngine.connect(self.audioEngine.inputNode, to: self.mixer, format: format)
```

You know it by print `mixer.inputFormat(forBus: 0 )`

---

then you got sample rate 48000 by the actual device. you can get 44100 by converting

---

just use `AVAudioConverter` to do down sample audio buffer.

```
let input = engine.inputNode
let bus = 0
let inputFormat = input.outputFormat(forBus: bus )

 guard let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1, interleaved: true), let converter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputFormat, to: outputFormat) else{
        return
    }

if let convertedBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: outputFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(outputFormat.sampleRate) * buffer.frameLength / AVAudioFrameCount(buffer.format.sampleRate)){
            var error: NSError?
            let status = converter.convert(to: convertedBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputCallback)
            assert(status != .error)
            print(convertedBuffer.format)
        }
```

Comment: My crash is happening also with pcmFormatFloat32.
What is different from pcmFormatInt16 to pcmFormatFloat32. Can you shed some light on this? Why we should use pcmFormatFloat32?

Comment: When do sampling , sample rate and bit depth do matter. `pcmFormatFloat32` and `pcmFormatInt16 `  are units of bit depth . `pcmFormatFloat32` is more accurate， comparing  to `pcmFormatInt16 ` ......

Answer (score 3):

The down sample part , more vivid on your case.

```
    let bus = 0
    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    let inputFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: bus)
        
    let outputFormat = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1, interleaved: true)!

    let converter = AVAudioConverter(from: inputFormat, to: outputFormat)!

    inputNode.installTap(onBus: bus, bufferSize: 1024, format: inputFormat){ (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
                
                var newBufferAvailable = true
    
                let inputCallback: AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { inNumPackets, outStatus in
                    if newBufferAvailable {
                        outStatus.pointee = .haveData
                        newBufferAvailable = false
                        
                        return buffer
                    } else {
                        outStatus.pointee = .noDataNow
                        return nil
                    }
                }
    
                let convertedBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: outputFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(outputFormat.sampleRate) * buffer.frameLength / AVAudioFrameCount(buffer.format.sampleRate))!
    
                var error: NSError?
                let status = converter.convert(to: convertedBuffer, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputCallback)
    
                // 44100 Hz buffer
                print(convertedBuffer.format)
                
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Only saw this in the iOS simulator:
I spent over an hour going down a rat hole on this.  I had worked on a Logic audio session with some headphones (at 48K) on and then went over to my iOS simulator to work on my audio code for my app and started getting this crash.  Unplugged my headphones, still crashed.  Rebooted simulator, deleted app from the simulator, restarted XCode and machine, still crashed.

Finally I went to system preference on my mac, selected:
Sound & Input, plugged in my headphones so it says "External Microphone".

Also went to the simulator I/O settings for audio input set to "Internal Microphone"

Now my app was able to startup in the simulator without crashing while trying to create an AKMicrophone()...

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer but it didn't work for me.

I was able to fix it by declaring `audioEngine` instance variable as `optional`. Right before when I need to monitor or record sound. I used to assign a new object of type `AVAudioEngine` to it.
Upon ending the recording session. I call `audioEngine!.stop` and then assign it to `nil` to deallocate the object.